# Newly installed Metal Electrical Panel door will not open easily?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I just had a new metal entry box installed on the exterior of my home. I am unable to open the metal door, even with a tool. Not sure what the problem is however if the door was installed and not plumb with the box frame, could this be the problem? My neighbor came down and he had difficulty opening it and said it should not be that hard to open.Thanks.[image]

Comment: Can you upload a picture?

Comment: I'm assuming you had an electrician install it??  Proper operation of the door should be a part of any such job.  I suggest having the installer come back and correct the problem.

Comment: He is a licensed electrician however I noted he was rather sloppy during installing of panel. After it was inspected by Code he came back to add a surge protector. When he installed it with the green light facing the ground, I asked if that was the way it was suppose to be and he said” it is ok like that”.When I could not see the green light I called Square D and they affirmed it should not be facing the ground? He is coming back to install another one I picked up with front facing light. His should have been side mounted. He has to use the same opening or there would be a hole in the box. TX

Comment: Whats wrong with door? Or is the panel out of square and racket making it not work .Seen that.

Comment: Why did he have to add surge? Is that state code?

Comment: He's not wrong about the surge suppressor.  They don't care about orientation, they are all solid state.   Not that important to see the light, but *what is valuable* is keeping it out of the weather.  I would put it entirely inside the panel.  Unused box holes are very easy to plug. Also save your other surge, they are very useful and can be put on any circuit for extra protection...

Comment: The door i thlnk if you lift it a little unhooks . then swings out..Or you flick that tap.

Comment: While he is there a couple of two whole straps on the conduit ,would not hurt. And are all the runs in those pipe?

Comment: @ Robert Moody I will try again however I could not budge that door. My neighbor pushed the clip mid door to the left however still had problems popping the door. He said his door opens much easier.

Comment: He deliberately only added one strap. I think he only did bare minimum work for what he got paid. Lesson learned to get a detailed estimate for any work to be done in the future. You can see the black adhesive on the outside of the PVC. Never bothered to clean it off and now it is permanent.

Comment: Yeah, if you can get that door open and take photos of it with the door open, that'd be great please

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I will ask my neighbor to open the box on Saturday for me so I can do an inside photo thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is a "NEMA 3R" enclosure, meaning it is rated to be used outdoors. The door for those often have a "trick" to opening them because they are designed to keep rain out even when open, so there is a "drip lip" over the door. That sometimes requires that after you unlatch it, you must lift the door up from the bottom a little bit to get it off the catch, then let it drop down so that it will get clear of the lip and allow it to swing open.

If it's not that, then all he probably needs to do is shim the back of it. It appears as though he removed something else to put this in, and the wall behind it may be uneven. having to shim the back of the new panel is very common, the sheet metal is thin so any unevenness in the surface warps the box into a parallelogram. It can often just be done by putting washers on one or more of the mounting screws, BETWEEN the wall and the back of the panel.

Comment: @J Raefield that makes sense! The surface behind is stucco and after he removed the old box there were rough edges. I had to ask him to knock them off. He was going to leave lumps of stucco. I bet the wall is uneven behind the box and it is not sitting flat on the wall, resulting in the box not being square. I will try your door suggestion and see if it works. The clip is so tight that I have to force it over with all my mite( I am no weakling either). I dread discussing this with him on Monday. The door catches on the surge protector when it is opened or closed also ☹️

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions! The electrician returned and told me that he installs all the surge protectors with the light facing the ground and it is personal preference to be able to see it directly rather than standing on their head!  His wife insisted that the Square D rep who told me it was installed incorrectly was only trying to up sell me. She got upset when I told her no, that they had not installed as manufacturer expected. He made an adjustment on the latch and now I can open the door! So happy to be done with them!!

Comment: Actually, there is nothing in the installation instructions for that SPD that dictates a right or wrong way to install it. it only says that you should be able to see the LED. Given that the box is outdoors, I may have mounted it on the bottom like that too because it gives it some protection from physical damage and rain as opposed to being on the side. You can't mount it on the cover.